# DynamoDB batchGetItem returns error: "Supplied AttributeValue is empty"

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Both the hash and range are specified, yet it thinks one is empty? Or is it talking about some other attribute?

The task.result() that is returned is nil, and task.error() says:

> "Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSDynamoDBErrorDomain Code=0 "Supplied
>   AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the supported
>   datatypes" UserInfo=0x7ff3c0e21d40 {NSLocalizedDescription=Supplied
>   AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the supported
>   datatypes}"

I am sure that the hash and range names are correct, and so is the table name.

Writing in Swift, here is my code:

```
var venueIdAttribute = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
venueIdAttribute.N = "2164156"

var venueIdCondition = AWSDynamoDBCondition()
venueIdCondition.comparisonOperator = .EQ // Hash Key must always be Equals
venueIdCondition.attributeValueList = [venueIdAttribute]

var startDateAttribute = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
var startString = String(format:"%1.0f", lastSyncDate.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
startDateAttribute.N = String(format:"%1.0f", lastSyncDate.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)

var dateCondition = AWSDynamoDBCondition()
dateCondition.comparisonOperator = .GT
dateCondition.attributeValueList = [startDateAttribute];

var keysArray : NSArray = [["venueId" : venueIdCondition, "dateInterval" : dateCondition]]
var keysAndAttributes : AWSDynamoDBKeysAndAttributes = AWSDynamoDBKeysAndAttributes()
keysAndAttributes.keys = keysArray;

var requestMap : NSDictionary = ["myTableName":keysAndAttributes]

var request : AWSDynamoDBBatchGetItemInput = AWSDynamoDBBatchGetItemInput()
request.requestItems = requestMap

var response : BFTask = dynamoDB.batchGetItem(request)  // This is synchronous
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`keysArray` is not formatted correctly in the code snippet. You are creating a `NSString` : `AWSDynamoDBCondition` dictionary, but it needs to be `NSString` : `AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue` dictionary. The following reference may help understand how to format the `BatchGetItem` request.

- [BatchGetItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html)
- [KeysAndAttributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_KeysAndAttributes.html)
- [AWSDynamoDBKeysAndAttributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSDynamoDBKeysAndAttributes.html#//api/name/keys)

Comment: Right.  So you can't use conditions on BatchGetItem -- you can only get specific primary keys.  Bummer.  I was hoping to use it as sort of a BatchQuery, which does not exist.  Thanks for the help.